# Optional java 8 with "return" from methods

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Ok I would like to create a method that returns a String depending on some condition (whether the parameter is null or not) :

```
private static String getErrorMessage(String code, Object... params) {
    Optional.ofNullable(params)
              .ifPresent(params -> processWithParams(code,params))
              .orElse(() -> process(code));
}
```

Both methods processWithParams() and process() return String (the string value is the value I want to return from getErrorMessage() method), is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: `map` and `orElseGet` surely?

Comment: Just look at [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Optional.html) and pick the right methods, e.g. `map` and `orElseGet`. But you should rethink your approach anyway, as `getErrorMessage("foo")` will not provide a `null` array, but rather an array of length `0`.

Comment: Also note that unless someone passes `null` to your method explicity, `params` will be _empty_ rather than `null`.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 **not** `null`.

Comment: And either, `return params != null? processWithParams(code,params): process(code);` or `return params.length != 0? processWithParams(code,params): process(code);`, is simpler than using `Optional`.

Comment: 100% what @Holger said - pointless use of fancy Java 8 APIs just confuses what should be super simple code.

Comment: I think I should point out that this type of API call is hugely inefficient compared to if...else blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see why you should accept a caller passing `null` for `params`. If anyone calls `getErrorMessage` with just one argument, `param` will be an empty array (not `null`). So I suggest:

```
    Objects.requireNonNull(params);
    return processWithParams(code, params);
```

A caller is not prohibited from calling with `null` as the second argument. If your code already has many such calls and you don’t want to clean that up just now:

```
    if (params == null) {
        params = new Object[] {};
    }
    return processWithParams(code, params);
```

However, if for some strange reason you insist, Boris the Spider is correct:

```
    return Optional.ofNullable(params)
              .map(p -> processWithParams(code, p))
              .orElse(process(code));
```

Or if processing for no need is prohibitively expensive:

```
              .orElseGet(() -> process(code));
```